# How does nginx handle log file growth by default?

Tags: nginx, web-server, logging, log-files

I'm a bit worried because its been a couple of days and my access log file is up to 250MB+. Does it roll log files over and delete them? I'd like for there only to be 1GB or less of log files total.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike `apache`, which provides the `rotatelogs` utility, `ngingx` relies on the OS for this task, specifically in the `logrotate(8)` utility.

In the `nginx` [wiki](http://wiki.nginx.org/LogRotation), it is noted that file rotation can be safely handled using the USR1 signal.
The same wiki page links to the Debian default `lograte(8)` script installed along the `nginx` package:

```
/var/log/nginx/*.log {
        daily
        missingok
        rotate 52
        compress
        delaycompress
        notifempty
        create 640 root adm
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                [ ! -f /var/run/nginx.pid ] || kill -USR1 `cat /var/run/nginx.pid`
        endscript
}
```